# IntelliJ IDEA GUI builder – no Java code generated

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, code-generation, gui-builder

I have designed my GUI form in the IntelliJ IDEA GUI designer, and selected the radio button in [Project Settings → GUI Designer](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/gui-designer.html) to generate source code instead of `.class` files, but my `.java` file with code looks like this:

```
public class PovRayEmptyProjectWizardPanelVisual {
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JTextField textField3;
    private JButton button1;
}
```

That’s it – no code creating the GUI was generated. How do I manually trigger such code generation, so that I can compile the resulting `.java` file with Maven?

Comment: Are you sure the GUI form is bound to this class and the fields are mapped to the components in the form? Note that you need to `Build` | `Make` so that the code is generated into the source file, it will be in the folded section.

Comment: Yes, it seems like all i had to do is to run "Make project" inside of Idea, after this it generated missing source code alright. I never did any building in idea before - i was performing all compilation straightly with maven. Please, create an answer, so i could accept it. Also, please, include this url or technique described there to your answer, it might be helpful for someone who want to perform .java code generation from idea .form format with maven solely: http://www.glxn.net/?p=279

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Source code is generated on `Build` | `Make`. If you build externally, IDEA GUI forms can be compiled from Ant (`javac2` task provided with IDEA) or [Maven](http://www.glxn.net/?p=279).

Comment: Thanks! and if maven build fails, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547515/ant-build-for-intellij-idea-gui-forms