# Intellij Idea 13 UI Designer and automatic Gradle building

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea, gradle

I've used the Intellij UI Designer to create forms for a project. Everything works fine when I'm building with idea as it handles compiling the forms for me, but as we recently switched to using Gradle for building it hasn't been possible to produce an executable jar file yet.

My google-fu has led me to several posts that explains that an ant script is needed to compile (eg [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547515/ant-build-for-intellij-idea-gui-forms), [link2](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/437099), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482610/intellij-idea-gui-builder-no-java-code-generated) ,and the one i ended on following: [link4](http://grahamedgecombe.com/blog/using-intellij-ideas-javac2-in-gradle))

My project is a multi-module setup.

**root build.gradle**

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**supproject build.gradle**

```
apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = "dk.OfferFileEditor.OfferFileEditorProgram"

configurations {
    antTask
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
    compile project(":Shared:HasOffers Api")

    //dependencies for java2c
    antTask files('../../lib/javac2-13.1.1.jar', '../../lib/asm4-all-13.1.1-idea.jar', '../../lib/forms_rt-13.1.1.jar')
    antTask group: 'org.jdom', name: 'jdom', version: '1.1'
}

task compileJava(overwrite: true, dependsOn: configurations.compile.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, 'jar')) {
    doLast {
        println 'using java2c to compile'
        project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.mkdirs()
        ant.taskdef name: 'javac2', classname: 'com.intellij.ant.Javac2', classpath: configurations.antTask.asPath
        ant.javac2 srcdir: project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.join(':'),
                classpath: project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath,
                destdir: project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                source: sourceCompatibility,
                target: targetCompatibility,
                includeAntRuntime: false
    }
}
```

But even though the compilation is successfull, a Nullpointer exception is thrown the first time I try to access one of the fields the UI Designer created. So something is not being compiled correctly.

I'm probably missing some setting, but after unsuccesfully pouring several hours into forums and google I still haven't found any solution.

Comment: I did as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62507378/2979435) and it worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1

I found this issue still exists. It's at least somehow [documented](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gui-designer.html#dd461eef) now:

> If your build actions are delegated to Gradle, GUI Designer will not generate Java source code.

So by **disabling** the according setting

`Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle`

I was able to build and run the project successfully. Note that I didn't need any other settings or additional libraries from the answers above. I let `Generate GUI into` be set to `Binary class files`.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I delegate Gradle for build/run actions and after a month I tried to implement GUI in my project. After disabling that option, now works perfectly, but I had to set `Generate GUI` to `Java Source Code`

Comment: I'm using IDEA Community 2020.1 with Gradle 6.4 on Windows. I don't have "Runner" in "Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle". Fortunately, I have "Build and run using:" option in the "Build and run" area on the "Build Tools | Gradle" panel. I fixed the same problem by changing it from "Gradle" to "Intellij IDEA".

Comment: this worked for me with the details described by @Zhou.

Answer (score 13):

So I made this a lot more complicated than needs be.

To make it work you need to change two things in your project.

#### A setting in IDEA 13.1.5

> Settings -> GUI Designer -> Generate GUI into: **Java source code**

This makes IntelliJ IDEA add 3 methods into the bottom of your forms:

- $$$setupUI$$$()
- $$$setupUI$$$()
- $$$getRootComponent$$$()

If they are missing try recompiling your project after you change the setting.

#### Add the missing classes

Intellij has a jar called **forms_rt.jar**, and I found mine in {IntelliJ IDEA Root}\lib. And renamed it to "**forms_rt-13.1.1.jar**"

This needs to be included during compile time to your project. If you are using Gradle as I did you could copy it to {project root}/lib and add a flatfile repository like so:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir dirs: "${rootDir}/lib"
}
```

After that you need to include it in your project gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile name: 'forms_rt', version: '13.1.1'
}
```

After that it should be possible to build it both in IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle.

Comment: This doesn't work.  You need a whole bunch of other Jars from the IDEA root lib dir in order to compile successfully.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I accepted this as the answer because it compiles from native gradle without any extra libraries added.

Comment: When I try this, I get copious compilation failures because stuff isn't on the classpath; specifically many of the other Jars from the IDEA lib dir.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

The `forms_rt` library is in mavenCentral.
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22forms_rt%22

Once you have configured IntelliJ to update the SourceCode it is sufficient to just add the library to the dependencies in your `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it seems that it's an older version. The forms_rt file that is in the intellij redist dir is bigger in size.
But I can't find any information about its version anywhere. Do you know if the mavenCentral is up-to-date?

Comment: Adding `compile 'com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3'` to gradle file made my proje ct work out of the box. Thanks, you saved my day,

Answer (score 5):

## Idea 2019.2

It seems like IntelliJ changed the settings UI when updating from 2019.1 to 2019.2, as the menu entry [mentioned by Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55725767/2201872) isn't there anymore.
I got it fixed by setting `Build and run using:` to **IntelliJ Idea**. I also changed `Run tests using:` to **IntelliJ Idea** to avoid problems while testing.
Both settings are located under `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle`.

Comment: This works with the other fixes above, worth noting you have to then run the Main program using the intellij run button at least once to generate the code, after that it will run with gradle

Answer (score 3):

I figured out an updated version of the gradle build workaround for a new project - https://github.com/edward3h/systray-mpd/blob/master/build.gradle
Probably won't use the form designer again though.

These are the relevant parts:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases" }
    maven { url "https://jetbrains.bintray.com/intellij-third-party-dependencies" }
}

configurations {
    antTask
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jetbrains.intellij.java:java-gui-forms-rt:203.7148.30'

    antTask 'com.jetbrains.intellij.java:java-compiler-ant-tasks:203.7148.30'
}

task compileJava(type: JavaCompile, overwrite: true, dependsOn: configurations.compile.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, 'jar')) {
    doLast {
        project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.each { project.mkdir(it) }
        ant.taskdef name: 'javac2', classname: 'com.intellij.ant.Javac2', classpath: configurations.antTask.asPath
        ant.javac2 srcdir: project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.join(':'),
                classpath: project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath,
                destdir: project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs[0],
                source: sourceCompatibility,
                target: targetCompatibility,
                includeAntRuntime: false
    }
}
```

The dependency versions for jetbrains libraries are found via https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/intellij-artifacts.html?from=jetbrains.org#using-intellij-platform-module-artifacts and https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/