# IntelliJ IDEA UI Designer form elements initialize to null

Tags: java, swing, gradle, intellij-idea

I started developing a simple tool on my laptop and wanted to move the project to my PC. Because i use version control I first simply cloned the repo, after that did not work I also tried copying the files.

After fixing some character issues, I get a `NullPointerException` when initializing my main form. I don't have that exception on my laptop.

I also found out that every single form element in the Java class is initialized to null, even though the form is bound to the class.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/N0W0RK/BWOrgaTool)

Comment: Do you build with IntelliJ IDEA or with Gradle? If the latter, UI initialization code will not be instrumented. Switch code generation to the Source files per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gui-designer.html. Open the project in IntelliJ IDEA, compile it (with gradle delegation disabled and the build set to IntelliJ IDEA: https://i.imgur.com/AmWjMZR.png). Make sure `$$$setupUI$$$` method is generated in the form class file. Now you should be able to build the same project with the command line Gradle as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind posting this as an answer? Also, is there any way I could have found this myself?

Comment: Did it solve the issue? Was the problem caused by building from Gradle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207997) when the build is delegated to Gradle.

The workaround is to disable the build delegation and switch compilation to IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: No delegation]

Another option is to configure Gradle to build the forms, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185378/intellij-idea-13-ui-designer-and-automatic-gradle-building).

Comment: it is sad that after 11 months the issue is not resolved(

Comment: The only answer that helped me after 1 hour of lookign around. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the solution ... But that can not be so, is there no better solution? Because there is no solution on the internet ...

Comment: Switching from gradle to maven also solved the problem for me.